# Unzip an archive in memory in PHP

Tags: php, zip, unzip

Is possible to unzip an archive in PHP in memory, i.e. without writing to disk? I am using curl to get the .zip file from GitHub, and want to extract it without dealing with disk permissions.

```
 $zip_file = Curl::get_request("https://github.com/user/repo/archive/v1.0.zip");
```

Comment: You could possibly extract an individual file to `php://temp`, but then what would you do with it? If you extracted the whole archive, to memory, what then?

Comment: Its getting parsed and insert into a database.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the ZIP functions http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

You can access a ZIP file with the zip_open and zip_read functions. You can also access files in a ZIP with the zip:// protocol

```
file_get_contents('zip://test.zip#test.txt');
```

Comment: I don't think I can pass binary/string into `zip_open()` though. The file has to exists on disk. Looking for a way around writing to disk.

Comment: You can't write it to tmp?

Comment: I can, but wondering if its possible to do this in memory? Writing to and from disk is just a waste for my use case.

Comment: ZipArchive cannot work with "memory mapped files" so no. Your best bet is to write it tmp and access it with the zip protocol. Duplicate of your question answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391969/in-memory-download-and-extract-zip-archive

Comment: This works, but I had to specify an absolute path, eg.: `file_get_contents('zip://'. dirname(__FILE__) .'test.zip#test.txt');`