# PHP ZipArchive strips tags from XML

Tags: php, php-ziparchive, phpword, phpoffice, odt

## Expectation

I have an ODT file containing the following content.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-content xmlns:officeooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/office" xmlns:css3t="http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/" xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" xmlns:textmaker="tm" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:formx="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooxml-odf-interop:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rpt="http://openoffice.org/2005/report" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0" xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xmlns:of="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:of:1.2" xmlns:calcext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:calc:xmlns:calcext:1.0" xmlns:tableooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/table" xmlns:drawooo="http://openoffice.org/2010/draw" xmlns:loext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:office:xmlns:loext:1.0" xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:field="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooo-ms-interop:xmlns:field:1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" office:version="1.3">
    <office:scripts/>
    <office:font-face-decls>
        […]
    </office:font-face-decls>
    <office:automatic-styles>
        […]
    </office:automatic-styles>
    <office:body>
        <office:text>
            <text:tracked-changes>
                <text:changed-region xml:id="ct94268758863184" text:id="ct94268758863184">
                    <text:deletion>
                        <office:change-info>
                            <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                            <dc:date>2021-11-07T19:03:50</dc:date>
                        </office:change-info>
                        <text:p text:style-name="P1">3</text:p>
                    </text:deletion>
                </text:changed-region>
                <text:changed-region xml:id="ct94268758864928" text:id="ct94268758864928">
                    <text:insertion>
                        <office:change-info>
                            <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                            <dc:date>2021-11-07T19:03:50</dc:date>
                        </office:change-info>
                    </text:insertion>
                </text:changed-region>
                <text:changed-region xml:id="ct94268772070912" text:id="ct94268772070912">
                    <text:insertion>
                        <office:change-info>
                            <dc:creator>Unbekannter Autor</dc:creator>
                            <dc:date>2021-11-07T20:03:35</dc:date>
                        </office:change-info>
                    </text:insertion>
                </text:changed-region>
                <text:changed-region xml:id="ct94268762403680" text:id="ct94268762403680">
                    <text:insertion>
                        <office:change-info>
                            <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                            <dc:date>2021-11-07T20:29:06</dc:date>
                        </office:change-info>
                    </text:insertion>
                </text:changed-region>
                <text:changed-region xml:id="ct94268772732144" text:id="ct94268772732144">
                    <text:insertion>
                        <office:change-info>
                            <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                            <dc:date>2021-11-07T19:03:50</dc:date>
                        </office:change-info>
                    </text:insertion>
                </text:changed-region>
                <text:changed-region xml:id="ct94268758865168" text:id="ct94268758865168">
                    <text:deletion>
                        <office:change-info>
                            <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                            <dc:date>2021-11-07T19:03:50</dc:date>
                        </office:change-info>
                        <text:p text:style-name="P1">
                            <text:bookmark-start text:name="__Annotation__40_4280670780____2"/>
                            t<text:bookmark-end text:name="__Annotation__40_4280670780____2"/>
                        </text:p>
                    </text:deletion>
                </text:changed-region>
                <text:changed-region xml:id="ct94268758865888" text:id="ct94268758865888">
                    <text:insertion>
                        <office:change-info>
                            <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                            <dc:date>2021-11-07T19:03:50</dc:date>
                        </office:change-info>
                    </text:insertion>
                </text:changed-region>
                <text:changed-region xml:id="ct94268764740400" text:id="ct94268764740400">
                    <text:insertion>
                        <office:change-info>
                            <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                            <dc:date>2021-11-07T20:06:36</dc:date>
                        </office:change-info>
                    </text:insertion>
                </text:changed-region>
            </text:tracked-changes>
            <text:sequence-decls>
                […]
            </text:sequence-decls>
            <text:section text:style-name="Sect1" text:name="Section2">
                <text:p text:style-name="P1">Test 1</text:p>
                <text:p text:style-name="P1">Test <text:change text:change-id="ct94268758863184"/>
                    <text:change-start text:change-id="ct94268758864928"/>
                    2<text:change-end text:change-id="ct94268758864928"/>
                    <text:change-start text:change-id="ct94268772070912"/>
                    <office:annotation loext:resolved="false">
                        <dc:creator>Unbekannter Autor</dc:creator>
                        <dc:date>2021-11-07T20:03:35.142766931</dc:date>
                        <text:p text:style-name="P3">
                            <text:span text:style-name="T1">Test</text:span>
                        </text:p>
                    </office:annotation>
                    <text:change-end text:change-id="ct94268772070912"/>
                    <text:change-start text:change-id="ct94268762403680"/>
                    <office:annotation loext:resolved="false">
                        <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                        <dc:date>2021-11-07T20:29:06.287838828</dc:date>
                        <meta:creator-initials>SH</meta:creator-initials>
                        <text:p text:style-name="P3">
                            <text:span text:style-name="T2">Antwort auf Unbekannter Autor (07.11.2021, 20:03): &quot;...&quot;</text:span>
                        </text:p>
                        <text:p>
                            <text:span text:style-name="T3">Answeeeeer</text:span>
                        </text:p>
                    </office:annotation>
                    <text:change-end text:change-id="ct94268762403680"/>
                    <text:change-start text:change-id="ct94268772732144"/>
                </text:p>
                <text:p text:style-name="P1">
                    <text:change-end text:change-id="ct94268772732144"/>
                    <text:change text:change-id="ct94268758865168"/>
                    <text:change-start text:change-id="ct94268758865888"/>
                    <office:annotation office:name="__Annotation__40_4280670780" loext:resolved="false">
                        <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                        <dc:date>2021-11-07T20:06:36.639407245</dc:date>
                        <meta:creator-initials>SH</meta:creator-initials>
                        <text:p text:style-name="P3">
                            <text:span text:style-name="T1">uppercase</text:span>
                        </text:p>
                    </office:annotation>T<text:change-end text:change-id="ct94268758865888"/>
                    <text:change-start text:change-id="ct94268764740400"/>
                    <office:annotation-end office:name="__Annotation__40_4280670780"/>
                    <text:change-end text:change-id="ct94268764740400"/>
                est 3</text:p>
                <text:p text:style-name="P1">Test 4</text:p>
            </text:section>
        </office:text>
    </office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

For those, who don't know the anatony of an ODT document, here are the contents of the zip file:

```
test.odt/
├─ META-INF/
│  ├─ manifest.xml
├─ Configurations2/
├─ Thumbnails/
├─ manifest.rdf
├─ meta.xml
├─ mimetype
├─ settings.xml
```

No matter how I do it, the resulting xml string always lacks certain tags. I checked this document with several validators but it appears to be valid xml.

## Solving attemps

All examples use the following variables:

```php
$zipFile = 'documents/Test.odt';
$xmlFile = 'content.xml';
```

Using [`ZipArchive::getFromName()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getfromname.php)

```php
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipFile);
$content = $zip->getFromName($xmlFile);
```

Using [`ZipArchive::extractTo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php)

```php
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipFile);
$targetPath = 'documents/extracts';
$zip->extractTo($targetPath);
$content = file_get_contents($targetPath.'/'.$xmlFile);
```

Using [this solution from stackoverflow by @hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392112/7451109)

```php
$path = sprintf('zip://%s#%s', $zipFile, $xmlFile);
$content = file_get_contents($path);
```

Using [`ZipArchive::getStream()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getstream.php)

```php
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipFile);

$contents = '';
$fp = $zip->getStream($xmlFile);
if(!$fp) exit("failed\n");

while (!feof($fp)) {
    $contents .= fread($fp, 1024);
}
fclose($fp);
```

## Result

The resulting document always looks something like that (the `<office:annotation />` tag is missing):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<office:document-content xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0" xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer" xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc" xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:textmaker="tm" office:version="1.0">
    <office:font-face-decls>
        […]
    </office:font-face-decls>
    <office:automatic-styles>
        […]
    </office:automatic-styles>
    <office:body>
        <office:text>
            <text:tracked-changes>
                <text:changed-region text:id="ct1">
                    <text:deletion>
                        <office:change-info>
                            <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                            <dc:date>2021-11-07T19:03:50</dc:date>
                        </office:change-info>
                        <text:p text:style-name="P7">3</text:p>
                    </text:deletion>
                </text:changed-region>
                <text:changed-region text:id="ct2">
                    <text:insertion>
                        <office:change-info>
                            <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                            <dc:date>2021-11-07T19:03:50</dc:date>
                        </office:change-info>
                    </text:insertion>
                </text:changed-region>
                <text:changed-region text:id="ct3">
                    <text:deletion>
                        <office:change-info>
                            <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                            <dc:date>2021-11-07T19:03:50</dc:date>
                        </office:change-info>
                        <text:p text:style-name="P7">t</text:p>
                    </text:deletion>
                </text:changed-region>
                <text:changed-region text:id="ct4">
                    <text:insertion>
                        <office:change-info>
                            <dc:creator>Sebastian Hädrich</dc:creator>
                            <dc:date>2021-11-07T19:03:50</dc:date>
                        </office:change-info>
                    </text:insertion>
                </text:changed-region>
            </text:tracked-changes>
            <text:sequence-decls>
                <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Tabelle"/>
                <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Abbildung"/>
                <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Grafik"/>
            </text:sequence-decls>
            <text:section text:style-name="Sect2" text:name="Section2">
                <text:p text:style-name="P7">Test 1</text:p>
                <text:p text:style-name="P7">Test<text:s/>
                <text:change text:change-id="ct1"/>
                <text:change-start text:change-id="ct2"/>
                <text:span text:style-name="T12">2</text:span>
            </text:p>
            <text:p text:style-name="P7">
                <text:change-end text:change-id="ct2"/>
                <text:change text:change-id="ct3"/>
                <text:change-start text:change-id="ct4"/>
                <text:span text:style-name="T12">T</text:span>
                <text:change-end text:change-id="ct4"/>
est 3</text:p>
            <text:p text:style-name="P7">Test 4</text:p>
        </text:section>
    </office:text>
</office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

Did I miss something or did I find a bug?

Comment: This one doesn't make any sense, you are extracting to a folder and then calling `file_get_contents` on that folder. `$zip->extractTo($targetPath);$content = file_get_contents($targetPath);`

Comment: That is just sample code I restored from my tries. The important information is that the method doesn't seem to matter, since the result is always the same.

Comment: Anyway - fixed it

Comment: I just tried the following, and the input and output files are identical, and I verified that using MD5, too. `$zipFile = dirname(__DIR__, 2).'/Desktop/Demo.odt';$xmlFile = 'content.xml';$zip = new \ZipArchive();$zip->open($zipFile);$content = $zip->getFromName($xmlFile);file_put_contents(dirname(__DIR__, 2).'/Desktop/'.$xmlFile, $content);`

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what the difference between the files is? Or perhaps try with a smaller file so that the problem is easier to show?

Comment: @ChrisHaas @IMSop Do you have comments in your file? It's the `<office:annotation />` tag in content.xml

Comment: @ChrisHaas I did that and it worked. But I can't tell the difference between your code and mine.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the different is either. If you could post a full-working example, including how you are comparing the two, it might help. Your examples have variables that are implied but that is still a potential source of difference

Comment: I added the variable contents. But to have the exact same code as I have, it wouldn't be a minimal [...] example anymore since I'm currently implementing reading comments from ODF into [`phpOffice/phpWord`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord).

Comment: So, how are you comparing the inside zip file with the extracted? Is it a byte comparison, string comparison, through an XML tool, or a visual one? If the latter, is it a `var_dump` or through a browser? I feel confident in saying that ZipArchive will not mess with the bytes of the extracted content, regardless of it being ODT file with XML, as that would defeat the purpose of its existence. So I would (with all due respect) lean on the side of the comparison itself being incorrect, especially if it is in XML where namespaces mess things up all the time.

Comment: I did a var_dump of the resulting string. That string was valid XML. So the error is not on the byte/string level but the XML level (which I haven't parsed yet at that point). So how come, that exact nodes are missing?